# What is the difference between a dense set and an $\varepsilon$-dense set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm reviewing for an upcoming exam for my metric spaces class and I am confused on two definitions I was provided. Here are said definitions as per my notes:

1. Recall: Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. $A \subseteq X$ is *dense* means that $\overline{\rm A} = X$ or in other words is $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\forall x \in X$ $\exists y \in A$ such that $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$.
2. $A \subseteq X$ is called *$\varepsilon$-dense* if $\forall x \in X$, $\exists y \in A$ such that $d(x,y) \leq \varepsilon$.

Is the difference between these two concepts just one being something about two points being stricly less than $\varepsilon$ and one being $\leq \varepsilon$? Why would we care about something being $\varepsilon$-dense versus just normal dense? Isn't something being normal dense a stronger condition? What is the motivation for using the latter definition over the former?

Thanks! :)

Comment: The former gets you arbitrarily close, the latter only guarantees $\epsilon-$close.

Comment: The set of integers is $\frac{1}{2}$-dense in the set of reals.  It is not dense in the set of reals.  Being dense means being $\epsilon$-dense for all positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: A set is dense if it is $\varepsilon$-dense for *every* positive $\varepsilon.$

Answer (score 1):

A set $A$ is dense if every point of $X$ is a limit point of $A$; meaning that for any $x  \in X$, you can get *arbitrarily close* to $x$ with points in $A$.

If $A$ is $\epsilon$-dense, it means you cannot get *arbitrarily* close,  but rather only that given $x \in X$, you can get within $\epsilon$ (for a *fixed* $\epsilon$) of this point $x$ from some point $a \in A$.

The  concept of $\epsilon$-dense can be thought of as a kind of resolution problem; if you are $\epsilon$-dense, you are "dense up to scale/resolution $\epsilon$".

Answer (score 0):

Exercise.  Prove in a metric space, A is dense iff
for all r > 0, A is r-dense.

Dense is a topological property,
e-dense is only a metric property.